# Removing Leading and Trailing Zeros along with a Case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I wanted to remove both leading and trailing zeros of a decimal record (for example: having .08 of a record 0.0800). This works very fine.

```
SELECT REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(cast(CAST(0.0800 AS decimal(6,2)) as float),'0',' '))),' ','0')
```

However, when I try to use it with a case, it is removing only the trailing zeros.

```
DECLARE @char int = 1

SELECT  
CASE WHEN @char = 1 THEN REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(cast(CAST(0.0800 AS decimal(6,2)) as float),'0',' '))),' ','0') 
ELSE 0.01
END
```

gives 0.08, while I'm expecting to have .08

However, this one gives 0.08

```
DECLARE @char int = 1

SELECT  
CASE WHEN @char = 1 THEN REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(cast(CAST(0.0800 AS decimal(6,2)) as float),'0',' '))),' ','0') 
ELSE cast(cast(0.01 as decimal(6,2)) as varchar) 
END
```

can anyone explain the reason? I'm just wondering.

Comment: The importance of data types to you is neatly summed up by `DECLARE @char int`. Therein lies the problem as forpas has capably explained.

Answer (score 3):

From [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.

And as you can find in [Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) any number data type has higher precedence than any `varchar` type, so this:

```
CASE WHEN @char = 1 THEN REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(cast(CAST(0.0800 AS decimal(6,2)) as float),'0',' '))),' ','0') 
ELSE 0.01
END
```

will return the same data type as `0.01`.
This means that although the `REPLACE()` function returns `.08` it will be implicitly converted to `0.08` and this is what you see.
In the 2nd version of your query where all branches of the `CASE` statement return the same data type, since the `ELSE` part returns `varchar`, the returned type of the statement is `varchar`, so you see what you expect: `.08`

Answer (score 1):

This really belongs in the presentation layer.  That stated, there is an alternative where you can format the number as string.

To be clear, `format()` has some great functionality, but the performance can suffer.

**Example**

```
Select format(0.080,'#.######')
```

**Returns**

```
.08
```